# Mythological figure for self-motivated seeking of unprejudiced knowledge

Tags: comparative, concepts

I am looking for the name of a mythological person, god, spirit etc. or narrative which stands for the unbiased search for knowledge or naive learning. I am not so much looking for famous examples for knowledge or wisdom in general, like maybe ancient greek Athena or Apollo, but more for something that reflects learning by doing from the perspective of someone unknowing, unaware, but curious. Maybe something that links the process of learning to making mistakes or starting from scratch or reinventing the wheel. It could also entail ultimate failure or slow growth as a notion. It does not have to come from a certain cultural background.

Comment: Perhaps Pandora from Pandora’s box? Pandora definitely was naive and curious, but her opening the box out of her burning curiosity led to ultimate failure, as the evil spirits escaped the box.